# Remove border and background when an image is inserted

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I developed an image input. My problem is that I can't remove borders and background-color when an image is inserted.

Does anyone know how I can remove this. Is it possible to make the image occupy the area 100% without distorting it?

Thanks

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmvgye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**code**

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="height:700px">
        <div style="height: 80%;">
          <div class="container" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
            <input accept="image/*" type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />
            <div class="abc" *ngIf="imageUrl">
              <img [src]="imageUrl" class="img-responsive drag" style="border-radius: 8px; object-fit: fill;">
            </div>
          </div>     
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Comment: You mean bluish background?

Comment: @Mridul 
Yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `[ngClass]="(imageUrl) ? 'container has-image':'container'"` 
and

`&.has-image {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}`

```css
&.has-image {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" style="height:700px">
  <div style="height: 80%;">
    <div [ngClass]="(imageUrl) ? 'container has-image':'container'" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
      <input accept="image/*" type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />
      <div class="abc" *ngIf="imageUrl">
        <img [src]="imageUrl" class="img-responsive drag" style="border-radius: 8px; object-fit: fill;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect both in the image and in the background, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ngStyle`

```
<div class="container" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)"
          [ngStyle]="fileDropRef.value ? {'background': 'none', 'border': 'none'} : {}">
            <input accept="image/*" type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />
            {{fileDropRef.value}}
            <div class="abc" *ngIf="imageUrl">
              <img [src]="imageUrl" class="img-responsive drag" style="border-radius: 8px; object-fit: fill;">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple as :

app.component.ts:

```
      <div class="container" [class.uploaded]="imageUrl" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
        <input accept="image/*" type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />
        <div class="abc" *ngIf="imageUrl">
          <img [src]="imageUrl" class="img-responsive drag" style="border-radius: 8px; object-fit: fill;">
        </div>
      </div>
```

app.component.scss:

```
    .container {
    ...
      &.uploaded {
        border: none;
        background: none;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The borders disappeared, but the backgroud color (blue) did not :(

Comment: You should be able tofind where the background is set by inspecting the dom and adjjust the css..